# Find bounding box of a Google map

Tags: web-mapping, google-maps, javascript

Is it possible to get the bounding coordinates of a google map that a user has zoomed to using Javascript? I see that it can be done [using](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geospatial.html) the Google App Engine but I don't know if is possible using the Google Maps API (Version 3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about getBounds() method on the Map object: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Comment: Thank you - yes that is it exactly. I must have missed it!

Comment: FYI Geocoding response >Viewport also returns this info too. http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingResults